# Не добавляются классы при скролле до 90% от высоты страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var scrollHeight = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
  );

  var mh = scrollHeight / 100;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > (mh * 90)) {
      $(".trial-lesson-light .auto a").addClass("animated  flipInX");
      $(".trial-lesson-light .moto a").addClass("animated  flipInX");
    } else {
      $(".trial-lesson-light .auto a").removeClass(" flipInX");
      $(".trial-lesson-light .moto a").removeClass(" flipInX");
    }
  });
});
```

Вычисленную высоту страницы записал в scrollHeight, значение одного процента от высоты страницы записал в переменную mh. Смотрел с помощью alert, вроде работает. Но если в условие подставить mh * 90 то классы не добавляются при скролле. Если задать число вместо "mh * 90", то работает. Подскажите, что не так?

С использованием JQuery тоже самое, высоту считает, но если в условие подставить формулу то ничего не происходит.

html

```
<section class="trial-lesson trial-lesson-light">
    <div class="auto">
        <div class="info">АВТО</div>
        <a href="#order" class="orange-button fancybox-inline" title="">ЗАПИСАТЬСЯ</a>
    </div>
    <div class="moto">
        <div class="info">МОТО</div>
        <a href="#order" class="orange-button fancybox-inline" title="">ЗАПИСАТЬСЯ</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: html разметку забыли

Comment: Добавил html-разметку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы что-то путаете в величинах, изучите поподробнее высоту элементов, их скроллирование.

Вот решение вашего вопроса: вначале рамка зеленая, прокручиваете вниз, добавляется два класса - красная рамка и желтый бек, прокручиваете обратно - один класс удаляется (желтый бек), красная рамка остается.

Пример на http://jsbin.com/setasefeho/edit?html,output (тут не увидите на маленьком окошке).

```js
$(function() {

  var scrollHeight = Math.max(
    document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
  );

  maxScrollValue = scrollHeight - $(window).height();
  // или
  //console.log($(document).height() - $(window).height());

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > (maxScrollValue * 0.9)) {
      $(".trial-lesson-light").addClass("animated flipInX");
    } else {
      $(".trial-lesson-light").removeClass("flipInX");
    }

  });
});
```

```css
* {} body,
html {
  height: 1000px;
}
.trial-lesson-light {
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 100px 20px;
}
.flipInX {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.animated {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trial-lesson-light">div</div>
<div class="trial-lesson-light">div</div>
<div class="trial-lesson-light">div</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение. Определение высоты элементов и их скроллирование изучу детальнее. 

Насколько понял, отсчет области скроллинга идет от нижней границы окна браузера, нужно делать вычитание высоты окна из высоты страницы, что не было сделано. Поэтому, значение в условие подставлялось слишком большое и классы не добавлялись.